# Problems about return different View

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is the code in controller:

```
[Route("{page:required}.html")]
public IActionResult Index(string page)
{
            int.TryParse(page, out int i);
            if (i!= 0)
            {
                //Return View A
            }
            else
            {
               //Return View B
            }
}
public IActionResult A(string i)
{
   //some logic
   return View(AModel);
}

public IActionResult B(int i)
{
   //some logic
   return View(BModel);
}
```

As the code above, I wanna achieve this:
When the page is an int(but not zero), then return the B view.
When the page is a string, then return the A view.
AModel and the BModel is different.
I have tried some ways:
For example, return `RedirectToAction` will change the URL.
Return `View` will throws an error:The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Sample.Database.BModel'.

What should I do to achieve this without change the URL?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you want to use a different view for each action it might help stating it explicitly:

```cs
public IActionResult A(string i)
{
   //some logic
   return View("A", AModel);
}

public IActionResult B(int i)
{
   //some logic
   return View("B", BModel);
}
```

---

The problem may be in the rest of your code, not shown here, but normally this should work:

```cs
[Route("{page:required}.html")]
public IActionResult Index(string page)
{
    int.TryParse(page, out int i);
    if (i!= 0)
    {
        return B(i);
    }
    else
    {
        return A(page);
    }
}
public IActionResult A(string i)
{
   //some logic
   return View("A", AModel);
}

public IActionResult B(int i)
{
   //some logic
   return View("B", BModel);
}
```

There is some inconsistency in what you are saying

> When the page is an int(but not zero), then return the A view.

> public IActionResult A(string i)

Comment: No, it reports the same error:The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'SealIndustry.Database.BModel'.

Comment: Then it's something caused by the code not shown here; you should add the rest of your code.

Comment: I am sorry about the inconsistency, I have corrected it just now.

Comment: @MelonNG - check the update in the beginning of my post.

Comment: Well, it works now. Would you please tell me what is the difference between return View("A", AModel); and return View(AModel);

Comment: @MelonNG - as you are returning it in `Index(string page)` it will normally use the `Index` view; specifying it in your A method will overwrite that and use the `A` view.